# Meaning of "honor quarter" for Cavaliers of the Order of the Blue Rose

Tags: pathfinder-1e

I'm not an English native, but English is my second language and translating a certain part using a dictionary, google and family I'm still wondering what "honor quarter" means for the Cavaliers Order of the Blue Rose edict found  [here](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/ultimateCombat/classArchetypes/cavalier.html):

> He must also honor quarter when he gives it, protecting captives who have surrendered from his own allies if need be.

I'm sure it doesn't mean honor 25%. But that is the only meaning dictionaries give me.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

## *Quarter* can also mean *mercy*

*To give someone quarter* means to spare someone who you could easily kill and letting them get away. In this context it means that if someone surrenders your honor dictates that you don't kill them and that you don't go back on your promise not to kill them at a later time. So when you accept someone surrendering and at a later time you have problems because there are more mouths to feed you won't kill them to have an easier life. You honor the quarter that you gave your captives. Even if your teammates suggest to kill them because they are a hassle: you promised to show mercy and not kill them if they surrender, so you will defend your captives from your teammates.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_quarter